# Dynamic URL that forwards all requests to dedicated Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, websocket, video-streaming, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to use a kubernetes cluster to do on-demand live transcoding of a video stream from multiple ip cameras, and send via websocket to a website.

I've modified a project I found online written in go, which takes a web request with a payload of the rtsp feed URL, it then uses the url to start a FFMPEG process to access the stream and transcode it to MPEG and sends the mpeg data to another endpoint on the go app, which starts a websocket connection. The response to the orignal request includes a websocket url when the stream can be accessed. Which the url can be put into a mpeg js player and viewed in a browser over the websocket. Main advantage is multiple clients can view the stream while there is only one stream coming from camera which reduces mobile data. I will also add that the FFMPEG automatically stops after 60 seconds with a request isn't set to endpoint.

The problem I can't find a solution to, is how can I scale the above application in a kubernetes cluster, so when I request comes in it does the below. 
-> Checks to see if someone is already viewing stream 
----> If someone is viewing, means a pod and websocket connection is already created. So a url that points to the pod just needs to be sent back to client.
----> If no one is viewing, a streaming/websocket pod needs to be created and once created a url sent back to the client to access stream.

I've looked at ingress controllers possibly dynamically updating the ingress resource is a solution, or even possible using a service mesh, but these are all new to me.

If anyone has any input to give me a bit of direction down a path, it would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1):

Having your application dynamically configure K8s sounds like a complicated solutions with possible performance implications due to a very large object of ingress objects. You might have to look into how to clean those up. Also, doing this requires a K8s client in your app.

I would suggest to solve this without the help of K8s resources by simply having your application return a HTTP redirect (301) to that websocket URL if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I did see that as an issue regarding a large hard to manage ingress resource. 

So are you suggesting I don't use kubernetes as the infrastructure? or still use it but have the pod that handles the response return the HTTP redirect? The question I have for the second, is how does the kubernetes cluster know where to forward the websocket url returned? A websocket proxy maybe?

Comment: The use of Kubernetes would have to be decided on a cost-benefits analysis independent from the technical issue at hand. For your particular usecase, you would benefit from easy scaling for the Deployment that takes the initial request as well as scaling for the Deployments that provides the web service endpoints if need be. For the redirect solution to work your websocket url would need to be absolute and externally available, e.g. https://www.example.com/mywebsocket/id since the redirect would be done by the client.

Comment: I believe the use of kubernetes would be beneficial in the fact pods can start ondemand a lot quicker than a node. But saying that I am not set on kubernetes.

But I am still not quite following what you mean, but is what you'r trying to say is have a pool of preset url's that you can assign temporary to a deployment whilst someone has an active viewing session?